# Mysql is automaticlly creating an extra row when a data is inserted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to create an article based website using codeigniter. When any article is requested to fetch from database for viewing, I use the following code to mark the number of unique view of each article in a separate table called "hits".

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO hits(ip,article_slug,hitcount) 
                 VALUES('$ip_address','$id',1)
               ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hitcount=hitcount+0");
```

I get the value of article_slug from `$this->uri->segment(3);`

Now the above query works fine but the problem is, in the database it adds one extra row for each unique article view and I have no idea where it is coming from. the table looks like this

Table: hits

```
     ip                         article_slug                          hitcount
 127.0.0.1    valid.png //<<no idea where the valid.png comes from       1
 127.0.0.1    making-a-seo-friendly-url-for-a-cms                        1
```

I am running it on localhost.Could you tell me how to get rid of creation of the extra row that is producing valid.png

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the page you're requesting possibly contain an image link to 'server.com/valid.png' ? In which case if it doesn't have a shortcuted static file access (.htaccess) it maybe interpretted by your front controller like any other request. Possibly light up firebug and check out all the http requests being sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot Smassey. As you suggested I used the firebug and found that I had an image called valid.png in my view file (didn't know about it :)) and the image location was not correct. I then removed the image and it is working fine now. Thanks man :)